# MySQL Stored Procedure in SSIS destination

Tags: mysql, ssis

Is it possible to use MySQL stored procedure in DataFlow task destination? 
While SQLServer is the source, MySQL DB is the destination, and I would like to use stored procedure to normalize the data. Currently the process uses ADO NET Destination with ADO.NET connection manager to insert data into a single table and it works.

Answer (score 0):

Well, Yes you can use it. But take care about Connection of MySQL and Parameters you passed to Stored Procedure.

Current System and use of StoredProcedure both will work for same.

Comment: I don't see a place holder to call SQL command, as the destination has only table/view in the list. Where should the parameters be passed?

Comment: you can use Execute SQL Task in Package or in DataFlowTask you can use OLE DB Command. and to pass parameter you can simply map the parameter use it in query

Answer (score 0):

You can't use a stored procedure as a destination, but you can use a staging table as a destination and then call a stored procedure that normalizes your data as it sends it to the destination tables.

Comment: Can there be any step after DataFlow Task to call this stored procedure?

Comment: Not in the dataflow.  Use an Execute SQL Task after the dataflow to call the stored procedure.